# Excel - Compare two whole numbers and return a value if there is a +-10% change

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have two columns A & B with dollar amounts. I need to return the value True in column C if there is a + or - 10% between columns A & B I would also need column C   to round up.

Thank you

Comment: 10% difference relative to which column?

Comment: How do you "round up" True or False?

Comment: Sorry, relative to column A round up- True

Comment: Can you give an example of the rounding up that you want? Are you wanting the difference to round up? If so, based upon what/which decimal place? Round up to the nearest percent?

Comment: Why the downvote on this question when it is clear? Most of the answers have very little thought to them and are more deserving of downvotes than the original question. This is not nearly as trivial of a question as it sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=IF(((B1-A1)/A1)^2 >= .01, True, False)
```

Comment: Squaring is clever to avoid using absolute values, but this is wrong because you forgot to also square the .1 and get >= 0.01.

Comment: +1 your answer is much more useful now. And the accidental mistake actually has served a good purpose. It generated this documentation for someone who is going to use it for a different value than 10%, so that they know how it works and that they need to square the decimal value of the percent that they want to use. If you explain that it your answer, I will delete my comment. (Your answer does not deal with zero divisors, but many people don't need to worry about those, and if they do, my answer is there for them.)

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(ABS((B2-A2)/A2)<0.1, "True", "False")
```

This gets the absolute value of the difference and then checks to see if it is less than .1 or 10%. Then it returns true if it is and false if it isn't. I'm assuming you want to check for a 10% difference from the value in column A.  I'm not sure what you mean by rounding up.  I can modify my answer if you will elaborate on that point.

Comment: No downvote, but this answer makes way too many assumptions and also gets the logic backwards. You are returning true if the difference is less than 10% of column A (i.e., *not* a 10% difference), while the original question says return true if there *is* a 10% difference. Additionally, it fails in likely cases of data. While you *may* be lucky and not have any zero values, in accounting you certainly may have negative values, and your solution crashes on both types of data. Also, why a string value of true or false instead of an actual boolean true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what is the question.... but if you are searching for a solution for the following problem: *"A must be between B+10% AND B-10%*", the following formula should help you!
I f A is between the range  B-10 and B+ 10 %, the if statement returns true;

```
=IF(AND(A1>=B1*0,9;A1<=B1*1,1);"True";"False")
```

*the other way would be B must between A+-10%:*

```
=IF(AND(B1>=A1*0,9;B1<=A1*1,1);"True";"False")
```

PS:You can not =ROUNDUP() or =ROUNDDOWN() a boolean value;

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP specified in a comment, "relative to column A," the original question is much more interesting and remains unanswered, and is worth answering.

If there is no order to the numbers, then the 10% difference should be measured based on whether *either* column is 10% different from the other. The unqualified statement is equivalent to "one of the numbers is at least 10% larger than the other" which always implies using the smaller number as the baseline.

*Thinking question*: If you have 12 dollars on Monday, have a loss of 50% on Tuesday, and a gain of 50% on Wednesday, how much will you have on Wednesday?

Also, none of the other answers handles anything but the simplest case properly. The full flow chart for the logic actually looks like this:

1. If there is no difference between the numbers, return False.
2. Otherwise, if one number is zero (meaning that the other one is not zero, because of step 1), return True.
3. Otherwise, return the truth value of whether `abs(b-a)/min(abs(a),abs(b))` is greater than or equal to 0.1 (**the division now and only now is safe, because the divisor is never zero**).

Implementing this logic efficiently in Excel can be done using the `AND` and `OR` functions, and avoiding division by zero can be done using the `IF` function.

```
=AND(B2-A2, OR(NOT(A2*B2), ABS(B2-A2)/IF(A2*B2, MIN(ABS(A2), ABS(B2)), 1) >= 0.1))
```

In the case that column A is the baseline and you only wish to base +/- 10% off of the value in column A, then most of this logic is still needed. The only change is

```
=AND(B2-A2, OR(NOT(A2*B2), ABS(B2-A2)/IF(A2, ABS(A2), 1) >= 0.1))
```

Note for the curious: Why is there an `IF` ending with a `1` in both values for column C? It is because Excel is very stupid and evaluates every part of a conditional, even the ones which should not be logically evaluated. So the division by zero is not avoided even by the logical AND and OR statements, because Excel evaluates the irrelevant part of the conditional anyway (at the same time as logically ignoring its result!). So the division by zero has to be explicitly avoided, or else it will cause the cell to show a division by zero error, no matter what the result of the logical statement actually was. Of course, placing a `1` in the denominator results in the wrong calculation, but that only happens in the case when a division by zero would occur, and in that case the logic returns one of the other statement results from AND or OR.

The formulas also work if any of the numbers are any mixture of positives, negatives, or zeros, i.e., any real numbers, but not non-real numbers like infinity. Example output:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? The other answers do not deal with either zeros or negative numbers correctly, both of which are likely in accounting, financial, and many other applications. My answer fully handles all of those cases, as well as either measuring 10% based on column A or from both columns A and B.